# When will palm's push notification go live? What are the alternatives right now?

Tags: push-notification, webos, server-push, palm-pre, palm

When will palm's push notification go live? What are the alternatives right now? We are in development of an app that needs push notification to function otherwise it will just not work. What should we do?

Comment: If you can't push, then poll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is something call [Mojo Messaging Service](http://www.precentral.net/mojo-messaging-service-webos-more-just-push). It is talked about a year ago. But not much news.